# Is "intermixed" a postpositive adjective in this text?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

The enemy advanced in two lines – the first composed of the mailed horsemen and the archers intermixed, the second of the elephants.

https://www.gutenberg.org/files/16167/16167-h/16167-h.htm

Comment: Yes, it modifies the noun phrase coordination "the mailed horsemen and the archers"

Comment: Which part of the question matters to you, whether it's a direct post-positive modifier, or the distinction between adjective and participle?

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan  Both of them

Comment: That it's a participle is supported by the facts that we can find the verb *to intermix* (giving us the forms "intermixed" and "intermixing") and that we can assume something resembling *agency* (something intermixed them or they intermixed themselves).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Participles can be used adjectivally. It is purely a matter of terminological convenience whether we distinguish between a "modifier" as a single category or break that category into the sub-categories of "adjective," "participle used adjectivally," and "attributive noun." The basic advantage of breaking the general category up is that adjectives proper in English never act as nouns or verbs whereas participles can act as nouns (gerunds) or components of a verb and nouns can obviously act as nouns. But it just complicates the issue when we are talking about the placement of modifiers.

So the phrase is a postpositive modifier. It is also a participle used adjectivally. What do you want to stress?

Answer (score -1):

> *The enemy advanced in two lines – the first composed of* [*the mailed*
> *horsemen and the archers intermixed*], *the second of the elephants.*

I wouldn't call it postpositive since "intermixed" modifies the whole noun phrase coordination "the mailed horsemen and the archers".

Some speakers (including myself) would call it an adjective, others a verb.

The important thing is that it functions as a modifier within the coordination.